# Why Hive shouldn't use TRUNCATE in its operations?

Tags: hive, hiveql

Why Hive shouldn't use TRUNCATE in its operations?
I heard that the reason why TRUNCATE is avoided in Hive and it can also cause problems, so why?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if `TRUNCATE` has issues in hive. It removes all data from file, update statistics and result an empty table ready for next load. If your files are clean and statistics updated, what else you expect from this command.
When someone says it has problems, there must be a strong reason behind it or they said from their past experience. But as per documentation and my experience i do not see this as an issue.
You can refer to this official link for more info - https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_truncate_table.html